# Drupal 6 Syntax Highlighting

Tags: drupal-6, tinymce, wysiwyg, syntaxhighlighter

I'm trying to implement adding code into my blog posts and prettyprinting it using [this technique.](http://cliffordmeece.com/content/drupal-wysiwyg-tinymce-syntaxhighlighter-redux)

When I insert the code using tinyMCE it looks properly formatted in the editor, when I hit save and view the page it all ends up in one long line. When I go back and edit it, the text has lost it's formatting and again is in one long line.

If I write some code within a tag without using tinyMCE, when it's saved it works perfectly. However if I then go back and switch to tinyMCE the tag and anything within it is replaced with with a single space (&nbsp).

I've also checked that I have no HTML filters applied to this input type etc.

Any suggestions? I'm pulling my hair out with this!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://drupal.org/project/codefilter - its the one used on drupal.org.  I've used it a couple of times with good results.  The only thing I had to do (in addition to following the installation instructions) was make sure it was the last filter applied - e.g go to :

Administer Site > configuration > Input formats> Full HTML > Rearrange

And drag Code filter to the bottom - looks simpler than the method you're attempting!